# SQL extract only latest modified record AND correct days count IN 3 table join

Tags: sql, postgresql

This query needs to do 2 things it's not doing at the moment:

1. If a h.name is strictly equal to other h.name, it should only select the latest record (where the h.modify_at is the most recent). Currently it selects all "h").
2. The following line: `(EXTRACT(epoch FROM (SELECT (NOW() - date_cible)))/86400)::INT  AS retard` should return the number of days before or above the `date_cible` in number of days. 
   At the moment it does give an int as number of days, however it's incorrect.

I'm basically being onboarded in a project nearly finished and have to work with entities as they are, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT 
  h.target_date,
  h.flux_id,
  h.modify_at,
  f.description,
  d.nom,
  d.date_creation,
  f.ordre,
  f.name,
COALESCE(h.target_date,d.deadline) AS date_cible,
(EXTRACT(epoch FROM (SELECT (NOW() - date_cible)))/86400)::INT  AS retard
FROM
public.flux_historique AS h 
LEFT JOIN public.flux as f 
INNER JOIN public.document as d
ON d.id = :docId
ON h.flux_id = f.id 
      WHERE
         f.id_system_droit_id = d.id_system_droit_id
```

:docId is a Symfony parameter.

Sample data from this query:

```
"2019-12-10 10:39:59"   15  "dzd"   "Rapport d'Evaluation ANTE" "2019-11-15 14:05:51"   1   "Lecture"   "2019-12-10 10:39:59"   2179
"2019-12-22 10:39:59"   121 "Naaaaaaan" "Rapport d'Evaluation ANTE" "2019-11-15 14:05:51"   2   "Relecture" "2019-12-22 10:39:59"   2179
"2019-12-23 10:39:59"   121 "Naaaaaaan" "Rapport d'Evaluation ANTE" "2019-11-15 14:05:51"   2   "Relecture" "2019-12-23 10:39:59"   2179
"2019-12-24 10:39:59"   121 "Naaaaaaan" "Rapport d'Evaluation ANTE" "2019-11-15 14:05:51"   2   "Relecture" "2019-12-24 10:39:59"   2179
"2019-12-25 10:39:59"   121 "Naaaaaaan" "Rapport d'Evaluation ANTE" "2019-11-15 14:05:51"   2   "Relecture" "2019-12-25 10:39:59"   2179
"2019-12-26 10:39:59"   121 "Naaaaaaan" "Rapport d'Evaluation ANTE" "2019-11-15 14:05:51"   2   "Relecture" "2019-12-26 10:39:59"   2179
"2019-12-27 10:39:59"   122 "non"   "Rapport d'Evaluation ANTE" "2019-11-15 14:05:51"   3   "Introduction"  "2019-12-27 10:39:59"   2179
"2019-12-28 10:39:59"   122 "non"   "Rapport d'Evaluation ANTE" "2019-11-15 14:05:51"   3   "Introduction"  "2019-12-28 10:39:59"   2179
"2019-12-29 10:39:59"   122 "non"   "Rapport d'Evaluation ANTE" "2019-11-15 14:05:51"   3   "Introduction"  "2019-12-29 10:39:59"   2179
"2019-12-30 10:39:59"   122 "non"   "Rapport d'Evaluation ANTE" "2019-11-15 14:05:51"   3   "Introduction"  "2019-12-30 10:39:59"   2179
```

Sample correct output:

```
1   "Lecture"   "dzd"   "2020-02-03 00:00:00"   2179
2   "Relecture" "Naaaaaaan" "2020-02-03 00:00:00"   2179
3   "Introduction"  "non"   "2020-02-03 00:00:00"   2179
4   "Introducure"   "puis si"   "2020-02-03 00:00:00"   2179
```

So essentially I need the correct output, with all the column requested from my own statement.

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result. Move the WHERE clause condition to the ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: Doing this I unfortunately get a syntax error.

Comment: Those backward JOIN's are so confusing when outer joins are involved. You should do FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON ... JOIN t3 ON ... to write much clearer code!

Comment: Sorry I'm onboarding this project and being pressured to deliver a few things so I understand this must be hell to look at. Sincere apologies, I'm just looking for a solution to be honest

Comment: Sample data with expected output will help more.

Comment: I added sample data, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your `JOIN` conditions.  Learn to interleave the `ON` clauses and to put the conditions in the correct `ON` clause.  If you want no filtering (as suggested by the `LEFT JOIN`), you need to use it consistently.

Then to get one row, use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (h.flux_id)
       h.target_date, h.flux_id, h.modify_at, f.description,
       d.nom, d.date_creation,
       f.ordre, f.name,
       COALESCE(h.target_date, d.deadline) AS date_cible,
       (EXTRACT(epoch FROM (SELECT (NOW() - date_cible)))/86400)::INT  AS retard
FROM public.flux_historique h LEFT JOIN
     public.flux f 
     ON h.flux_id = f.id LEFT JOIN
     public.document as d
     ON d.id_system_droit_id = f.id_system_droit_id AND
        d.id = :docId
ORDER BY h.flux_id, h.modify_at DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this query doesn't do, I have data I should'nt in terms of records..

Comment: your help allowed me to make a query which is closer to what I need and for that you have my deep thanks